# Strange search in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some kind of data set in elasticsearch. When executing the following query

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d
'{
    "query": {
        "query_string": { 
            "fields": ["258"],
            "query": "*toco*"
        }
    }
}'
```

I get one result where field 258 is [PhotoComment]. However, if you change the query to this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d
'{
    "query": {
        "query_string": { 
            "fields": ["258"],
            "query": "*omme*"
        }
    }
}'
```

then the search result is empty.

Explain why this happens?

Comment: Can you please share the mapping of field 258 as well as the configure index-time and search-time analyzer for that field?

Comment: Mapping "258" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "norms" : { "enabled" : false } }

Comment: Very old version, like 2.x something right?

Comment: Yes, version 2.3

Comment: Both of your queries work ok on recent 8.x versions and return the document as expected

Comment: So this is a bug in the old version?

Comment: Can you show the results you get from `curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty' -d
'{
    "analyzer": "standard",
    "text": "PhotoComment"
}'`

Comment: {
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "photocomment",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 12,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the reason for this strange behavior. It is in one of the filters that is used in the analysis. The settings are as follows:

```json
"analysis": {
     "analyzer": {
         "default": {
             "type": "custom",
             "tokenizer": "standard",
             "filter": [
                 "lowercase",
                 "english_stemmer",
             ]
         }
     },
     "filter": {
         "english_stemmer": {
             "type": "snowball",
             "language": "English"
         }
     }
}
```

Calling the analyzer shows that the text "[PhotoComment]" after the filter "english_stemmer" turns into "photocom", and the text "*omme*" into "omm". Accordingly, the latter is not included in “photocom” and the record is not found.

I have not found an explanation why the "english_stemmer" filter behaves this way.